# Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to "...\FormType::__construct() must implement interface

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to call `entityManager` in `formType`. I don't get why this is not working.

FormType :

```
private $manager;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $this->manager = $manager;
}
```

Controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(ProductsType::class, $products);
```

Services:

```
apx.form.type.product:
    class: ApxDev\UsersBundle\Form\ProductType
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

Error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to MyBundle\Form\FormType::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager, none given, called in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php on line 90 and defined

Comment: Your code looks right.  I am guessing you are not loading the services.yml file.  Are you able to access other services from your services.yml file?  Use bin/console container::debug to verify the service exists.  Also checks ProductsType vs ProductType.  In fact, the spelling is probably the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your services.yml file is being loaded and that you copied pasted in the contents then you have a simple typo:

```
# services.yml
class: ApxDev\UsersBundle\Form\ProductType
should be
class: ApxDev\UsersBundle\Form\ProductsType
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your error

> Argument 1 passed to MyBundle\Form\FormType::__construct()

So when you're instantiating `FormType` we're talking about the argument you pass like so

```
$form = new \MyBundle\Form\FormType($somearg);
```

Your definition says

```
public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
```

Based on the second part of the error

> must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager

it's obvious that `ObjectManager` is an interface. So what that means is you have to implement that interface in the object you're injecting into your class because that's what you told PHP to expect. What that looks like is this

```
class Something implements \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager {
    // Make sure you define whatever the interface requires within this class
}
$somearg = new Something();
$form = new \MyBundle\Form\FormType($somearg);
```

Comment: Nope.  He is defining the form type as a service which will take care of the injection: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service

Answer (score 1):

You defined your form as a service (in `services.yml`) but you're not using it as a service. Instead of `createForm` you should use `service container` to create form, so change:

```
$form = $this->createForm(ProductsType::class, $products);
```

into:

```
$form = $this->get('apx.form.type.product')
```

and read more about [defining forms as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services)

Comment: Nope: Things have changed in S2.8/S3: http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service

Answer (score 0):

Try in services.yml:

```
apx.form.type.product:
    class: ApxDev\UsersBundle\Form\ProductType
    arguments: 
        - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

Symfony 3.4